# different text styles in Ubuntu tty sessions

Tags: command-line, tty, text

toggling between tty1 & tty2, I notice tty1 is bold, and tty2, and all other subsequent tty, are also not bold. Im just wondering why there is a difference, and if that difference is further programmable. (such as tty3 red, tty4 green, tty6 fuchsia.... and so on)

Check it out on your machine:
press ctrl+alt+F1, then ctrl+alt+F2

I am observing this in Ubuntu Mate 18.04, 19.10, and 16.04

Output of `dpkg -l | grep plymouth`:

```
ii  libplymouth4:amd64                              0.9.4-1ubuntu1                                amd64        graphical boot animation and logger - shared libraries  
ii  plymouth                                        0.9.4-1ubuntu1                                amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer  
ii  plymouth-label                                  0.9.4-1ubuntu1                                amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - label control  
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo                 19.04.0                                       all          graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-mate-logo theme  
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-text                 19.04.0                                       all          graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-mate-text theme  
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text                      0.9.4-1ubuntu1                                amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - ubuntu text theme
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, then Plymouth may have some issues with changing view of ttys. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep plymouth` to the question. Are you using Nvidia video card (and with which driver if so) ? Do you use LightDM or GDM?

Comment: Evidently I have lightdm, and gdm3 installed, how can I tell which one I am running?

Comment: They look different - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager for screenshots :) And what about video card? Is it Nvidia?